# How to find connection string from a phpMyAdmin database?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, connection-string

I want to connect from java, to a database which i am currently managing from phpMyAdmin.
I do not own the server which the database runs.

however, i want to find the connection string of that database, in order to be able to communicate with my database using java.

Does anyone knows how to find that connection string?

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the phpMyAdmin PHP files, then you can look into the `config.inc.php` file, there is the config of the database connection.

Comment: Just a note, this file is located in the phpMyAdmin folder.

Comment: for wamp -> C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\config.inc.php

Answer (score -1):

Here is the string syntax for MySQL, the backend of phpMyAdmin.

```
"server = localhost; port = 3306; user = <phpMyAdminUsername>; password = <phpMyAdminPassword>; database = <database>"
```

Replace localhost with the IP address if using a remote database.